I cannot run or debug normally on Vs code (flutter)
A few days ago, I ran vs code normally but found it looking like this

There is no Debug icon or menu to choose the emulator.
I did not understand what the problem was, so I restarted the PC and also tried to erase and restart vs code, but the problem was not solved either.
flutter doctor

Everything is fine with him. When I enter Android Studio, I found that everything is fine. I encountered some small problems with the emulator, but everything went smoothly after I reset it, but for Vs code, the problem is still the same.
Later, I found that if I go to the terminal and type flutter run, and if I open an emulator on Android Studio, I found it and I can select it as well, and everything will work smoothly, but I can not run vs code in the normal way.
This problem is very annoying to me because I do not understand its cause. Has any of you encountered this before or does anyone know how to solve it?

I tried to reinstall vs code
I also tried to restore its settings to how they were before.
I tried to look for any option that hides the run button.
I also tried to use this button


But no matter how much I pushed it, nothing changed.

"Flutter" and "Dart" Plugin in VSCode is installed and up to date?
